# I can't change bass notes while fingerpicking

Tags: guitar

Whenever I try to change bass notes with my thumb, like changing from a C chord to a D chord, I have to change my bass notes. I have trouble locating the different strings without looking and it slows down my playing. Thanks and PLEASE HELP.

Comment: not a full answer, but if you practice doing it really, really slowly and increase speed as you get confident, it should be a rear view mirror problem pretty quickly.

Comment: I've had the same problem and solved it by mentally forming a picture of the strings and where I want to go with the pick.  Like looking at them, but only in your mind.  It worked surprisingly well.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is no magic bullet.  Just practice.  A teacher might come up with some more targeted exercises specifically catered to your current problem and progress, making things a bit smoother.  But in the long run, this is just something that is going to take practice.

Answer (score 1):

Place the guitar in a comfortable position with the neck tilted up and perhaps the body of the guitar between your legs propped on the left thigh (if you are right handed). Pick 2 chords that you want to alternate between - for example E and A. Your thumb picks the 6th string closest to you for E and the 5th string for A.
Use 3 fingers (#1, #2, and #3 -pointer, middle and ring) together and pick the top 3 strings as you alternate the bass. The slash symbol (/) indicates the 3 fingers picking the top strings together.  GO SUPER SLOW!
Here is the pattern:
BassE / / /
BassA / / /
BassE / / /
BassA / / /
If this is too hard, just alternate the BassE and BassA with your thumb counting the beat.  Go slow. slow, slow until you get it.  Then add the chords.
E and A are the best chords to start this with because they define the bottom 2 strings and are the basis of bar chords. But choose any two chords you can play easily.
For D chord the Bass is the 4th string
For C chord the Bass is the 5th string, third fret (part of the C chord)
For G chord the Bass is the 6th string, third fret (part of the G chord)
If you love guitar you will practice until it hurts and then try again later.  The guitar will love you back if you love it.  Don't worry about perfection. Its all approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Until your hand has developed muscle memory this will be the case.  There are some systematic exercises that can help with the development.

When confronted with a new chord or chord transition I teach my students to practice moving from one to the other by choreographing several movements.  For example, moving from C to D and back give each chord 4 beats and do the following:

On beat 1 play C

On beat 2 release the C chord

On beat 3 move to D and set the fingers where they need to be

On beat 4 press the fingers down and place the right hand on the correct strings.

On beat one play D

Repeat.

I realize this is not what you are asking about but the same applies to the right hand.

There are exercises for getting right hand position in the muscle memory.  For example place the right hand fingers on the correct strings for the C chord and the D chord and practice playing those open strings no left hand.  This is the foundation of the Papararo exercises in classical guitar.  In other words we isolate the left and right hands and practice the movements until each is correct then put the two together.

Also, it is not typical to look at the hands.  With proper training and lessons you should be learning to "feel" you way around the fingerboard.  It sounds to me like you have not had some of these basic exercises.  If you look for them and devote a few minutes a day warm up you will correct these issues fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an experience thing. It'll come with practice; you just have to be patient and tenacious.

Playing guitar is a lot like learning to type - when you start, you have to stare at the keys and slowly locate each one. Then you get to a point where you can type fairly quickly but still need to look. Then you can type without looking.

The same is true for playing guitar - you start off slow and inefficient, but repetition (and maybe even some targeted exercises) will get your fingers familiar with the motions necessary to do this without slowing you down. Just make sure you don't rush things, or else you'll end up developing bad techniques and it'll slow you down in the long run as you need to un-learn any bad habits which are holding you back.